# How to dismiss NSViewController when NSButton is clicked programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

How can I dismiss a NSViewController when a subview NSButton is clicked?

I can't access to NSViewController from function of NSButton *mouseDown* so I can't write a code similar to:

```
 self.viewController.dismissController(self)
```

I need to set this programmatically, the same result when you connect via Assistant Editor a NSButton Action to its owner ViewController.

Comment: If it's a subview of the controller you can get a reference with `superView` or pass a reference when the view is added or presented.

Comment: Not sure for mac but you can try button's addTarget method ...

Comment: @vadian on superview I can't call dismissController (and I can't cast superview to NSViewController because type are not correlate).

Comment: @mihirmehta This method exists but I can't assign a value to this target var because I have no reference to ViewController

Comment: Unfortunately you're providing quite poor information about the relationship between the views / controllers. If the view controller containing the button is presented by a parent view controller using a storyboard, you can also get the reference with `presentingViewController`

Comment: You can create your own protocol and implement that in your viewcontroller and than call like [delegate protocolMethod]; //which will be implemented by view controller

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the target and action on controls in code.

In your view controller:

`self.button.target = self;`
`self.button.action = @selector(dismissController:);`

Should be good to go.